# Should I ask my boss for their job if they're leaving?

Tags: professionalism, promotion, recommendation-letter

I'm the type of person who doesn't realize when something is out of bounds. My boss is stepping down into a lesser role because she just had a baby and wants to spend more time at home. I've applied for the job and gotten my supervisors and their supervisors recommendations as they don't want it. However I'm hesitant to email the boss, like the boss of this entire branch and ask for her own recommendation to corporate.

Last year when I was considering leaving after college I did get a Letter of Recommendation from her, but that sure wasn't meant for her own job. Would it be considered crass to email her and ask her to put in a good word with corporate?

Comment: it's not crass unless you're well-known enemies and the ask is sarcastic. without knowing more, it sound like there's no harm in asking, especially if she won't be your boss later (if she declines for some reason).

Answer (score 8):

If she's stepping down, then it's not like you're pushing her out.

Just go in person and say:

> hey, I've applied for the job as «title» and would really appreciate your endorsement.

Comment: Agreed, though you may like to add some directions on the right language for phrasing such a request.

Comment: @cronax I thought I did?

Comment: You added a sample sentence, I'm suggesting to add some reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you should.** I see nothing crass or out-of-bounds about this request. You aren't taking anything from her, and if you're getting the recommendation of multiple supervisors above you, you aren't trying to overstep your capabilities. If you've already gotten one letter of recommendation, then the worst result I can imagine is that she will decline to recommend you. Let her know that you are interested in her position when she vacates it and ask if she might endorse you.